# Nokia Lumia 635 is stuck in narrator mode

Tags: accessibility, narrator, lumia-635

My Nokia Lumia 635 is stuck in narrator mode. I have already tried the Volume Up and Start buttons. I have also tried the Start and swipe up with two fingers.

Comment: Before trying a hard/soft reset, have you physically removed the battery and turned it back on?

Answer (score -1):

It's not the best option since **you will lose all your date**, but you can try the **HARD RESET**. If you want to save something, extract the MicroSD memory card if you have. 
I think Microsoft synchronize your contacts with OneDrive but I'm not sure if it always do or only if you configure the phone to save it's settings via Cloud. 
So it's a bit tricky and **I have never tried it** as my Lumia 720 usually works with Soft Reset, **but the hard reset guide says**:

> 1) Turn the **Power Off**. 
>   2) Press and **Hold** the **Volume Down**. 
>   3) While still holding the Volume Down **connect the charger or USB cable to PC**

For about **8 seconds** you will see an **exclamation mark (!)** on the screen if steps are done properly. (When you see the mark you can release the Volume Down key)

> Now press the keys in the following order: 
>   1) **Volume Up** 
>   2) **Volume Down**  
>   3) **Power**  
>   4) **Volume Down**

I repeat **I HAVE NEVER TRIED THIS** and **ALL YOUR PERSONAL DATA WILL BE DELETED**, but it seems legit to me and if I need a hard reset solution I will try it. 
**IF YOU CAN CONNECT THE PHONE TO YOUR COMPUTER AND BACKUP YOUR DATA YOU WON'T LOSE ANYTHING BUT YOUR APPLICATIONS AND CHAT HISTORY**

**Source Web Site where I found the solution:
http://www.hard-reset.com/nokia-lumia-635-hard-reset.html**

PS: This looks like playing super mario, vol up, vol down, power ... it should be a bit wired to accomplish but I hope It will do the job for you :)